# Record Stream in android.

Tags: android

I have a problem that i want to record the stream with the playing of media player. I mean if I am streaming and can record the stream with specific duration then how can i record it. ?

Please help.

Comment: Please can you be more specific... what are you trying to do... add some code

Comment: Thank you so much for response and Sorry for my late response.. Actually I have played a URL for late streaming of android media player. I want record a file with specific time. I think you have an idea about the tuneib application. I want to do like this.

Comment: URL url= URL.openConnection(); Inputstream i = url.getInputStream(); This is unknow length stream. when i record stream for 10 seconds , it record for 2 mintues.

Answer (score 0):

if you want 10 seconds you will have to calculate it, based on the number of bytes you have received and the bit rate of the file stream.

For your reference view this link:
[Record streaming audio in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351582/record-streaming-audio-in-java)