# How to limit record time with AudioRecord as MediaRecorder with setMaxDuration

Tags: android, audiorecord, android-audiorecord

I need to stop AudioRecord after 2 minutes from the starting time.
With MediaRecorder I use setMaxDuration and this work well, but I need a good approach with AudioRecord too.

Thank's for help

Comment: show the code you are using...[You can also try like this..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351582/record-streaming-audio-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this..

```
handler=new Handler();
 Runnable r=new Runnable() 
{
 public void run() 
{
  recorder.stop();
   recorder.release(); 
  } 

};
handler.postDelayed(r, 120000);
```

Comment: what does that mean ?